# Limit CPU usage for a user in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cpu-usage

I want to limit the percentage of CPU a user who ssh to my comp can use like say only 25% cpu usage at max. How do i do this in ubuntu ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you can't do that. What you can do is modifying priority for user. You can do that by editing file `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
john hard priority 20
```

Sets priority for john's processes to 20 (effective after next login). 20 is lowest priority.

This way john can use 100% of CPU, but if someone else needs it, other user will immediately get it, and john's tasks will wait (or actually slow down, not stop completely).

Comment: Not exactly what i am looking for. But since the other thing can't be done, i guess i'll have to work with this. Thanks a lot :).

Comment: `effective after next login` does that refer to next ssh login or next system reboot?